# C++ Delete array inside 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, heap-memory, free

Unfortunately I have to use arrays in order to use another function I have copied. Changing this function to work with vectors would be way over my head. So I wrote a function declaring me bunch of arrays in heap to be stored inside a vector.
I now have trouble freeing up that memory at the end.

```
void _get_X_Y_arrays(std::vector<std::vector<float> > *voronoi, std::vector<std::vector<int*> > *rtrn)
{
    int numberPolygons = voronoi->size();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberPolygons; i++)
    {
        int *x_heap = new int[((*voronoi)[i].size()) / 2];
        int *y_heap = new int[((*voronoi)[i].size()) / 2];
        std::vector<int> x(((*voronoi)[i].size()) / 2);
        std::vector<int> y(((*voronoi)[i].size()) / 2);
        unsigned j = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (; j < (*voronoi)[i].size(); j += 2, count++)
        {
            x[count] = (int)(*voronoi)[i][j];
            y[count] = (int)(*voronoi)[i][j + 1];

        }
        std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), &x_heap[0]);
        std::copy(y.begin(), y.end(), &y_heap[0]);

        (*rtrn)[i].push_back(x_heap);
        (*rtrn)[i].push_back(y_heap);

    }
}
```

The function works well and everything acts like intended. I wrote another function to free up that memory at the end when it's no longer needed:

```
void _cleanup(std::vector<std::vector<int*> > *rtrn)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rtrn->size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < (*rtrn)[i].size(); j++)
        {
            delete[] rtrn[i][j][0];
            delete[] rtrn[i][j][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this causes the program to crash. I don't really know where the error is. It feels like there might be an vector out of scope ..?
Just by looking at it and playing with it I'm not able to solve this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're clearly comfortable with vectors using vectors of vectors. Why do you then decide to start using dynamically allocated arrays?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but is there a reason you use pointers instead of references when passing your arguments?

Comment: your 'new's are in a single loop. Your 'delete's are nested in two loops. Are you sure you deleting the exact same number of arrays you created ? Start by printing the new'ed address and printing the delete'd address (before deletion). I bet the addresses won't match.

Comment: No there is no real reason ..I was just way into C code lately .. Might change this later on but should not affect the point that there is something wrong with delete[] or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 3 dimensions array [nbpolygons][2][nbpoints]

Your code :

```
delete[] rtrn[i][j][0]; // delete  rtrn[i][j] index 0
delete[] rtrn[i][j][1]; // delete  rtrn[i][j] (the same array) index 1
// => crash


rtrn[i].size() always egal 2
```

Do :

```
void _cleanup(std::vector<std::vector<int*> >& rtrn)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rtrn.size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < rtrn[i].size(); j++)
        {
            delete[] rtrn[i][j];
        }
    }
```

}

or

```
void _cleanup(std::vector<std::vector<int*> >& rtrn)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rtrn.size(); i++)
    {
        delete[] rtrn[i][0];
        delete[] rtrn[i][1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just figured out the same. I was trying to delete single elements inside the array not the array itself.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: i correct samples to use reference instead of pointer, because  delete[] rtrn[i][j] with rttn (pointer)  sould not compile

Comment: Yeah I did the same. I corrected both function to use the vectors by reference.